# Images not showing up on PDF created from HTML

Tags: javascript, image, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, html-to-pdf

I want to create PDF dynamically. That means I am taking files from Google Drive and then putting them in a HTML code and trying to create PDF out of it.

Everything is working fine , except images are not showing up.

What I am doing right now is :

1. Create HtmlOutput from HTML string.
2. Getting blob of that HTML.
3. Then that blob getAs PDF
4. Then finally saving that PDF in drive.

I thought maybe it need some time to render images so I have added sleep.

Alternative suggestions/solutions/code is also welcomed.

Here is the code I am using :

```js
function htmlToPDF() {
    var file1="0BweO_SXcQGqgcEV3Mk9QYVRMczQ";
    var file2="0BweO_SXcQGqgVU93ZU56WkRkN3c";
    var file3="0BweO_SXcQGqgMkIxTlhKajk5MFk";
    var html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'> <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> <title>High Return Real Estate</title> <style> @charset 'utf-8'; /* CSS Document */ body,html{ font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; background:#dfe7ea; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom:0; } .main_wrapper { width: 930px; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff; padding: 0 23px 0 23px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px -1px #bbbbbb; } .top_header { background: #dfe9e9; display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 6px; } .left_top { display: inline-block; width: 70%; padding: 26px 0 26px 50px; float: left; } p.contact_person.right_person { border-right: 0; padding-left: 25px; display: inline-block; } p.contact_person { width: 214px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #ccd4d3; } .left_top p span { font-size: 13px; color: #000; display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin-top: 2px; } .left_top p { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #ea9a5a; margin: 0; } .right_top img { border-top: 7px solid #496bb3; border-bottom: 7px solid #496bb3; padding: 16px 5px 13px 4px; } .right_top { display: inline-block; position: absolute; background: #fff; } .galleryimage_main img { width: 100%; display: inline-block; } .property_address { } .property_address p { font-size: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 4px; } .common_box_style { padding: 20px; background: #496bb3; text-transform: uppercase; } .common_box_style h2 { margin-top: 2px; color: #54bb73; font-size: 20px; } .property_information { margin-left: 6px; } .property_information ul li p { font-size: 15px; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 0; } .property_information ul li { list-style: none; margin-bottom: 5px; } .property_information ul li span { font-size: 15px; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 0; width: 100px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; } .property_information ul { padding-left: 0; width: auto; display: inline-block; float: left; margin-right: 15px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 4px; } .property_information ul li span.value_field { font-size: 13px; } ul.grpleft li span { width: 136px; } p.cash_prize { text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin: 0; } p.cash_prize span { padding-left: 10px; } .margintop{ margin-top: 6px; } .left_col { width: 34%; float: left; } .right_col { display: inline-block; width: 66%; } .gallery_small_images { display: inline-block; width: 99%; margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 6px; height: 232px; overflow: hidden; } .gallery_small_images img{ width:100%; } .gallery_small_image2 { width: 50%; float: left; } .gallery_small_image3 { width: 49%; display: inline-block; float: left; margin-left: 6px; } table.expense_info tr td.exp_info_disc { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: left; } tr.total_exp td { padding-top: 13px; padding-bottom: 30px; } .cashflow h2 { margin-bottom: 7px; } .roi input[type='text'] { font-size: 23px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; height: 33px; margin-bottom: 5px; } .roi h2 { margin-top: 24px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: 800; } tr.total_exp { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 4px; /* display: table; */ width: 100%; } table.expense_info th { font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; } td { font-size: 13px; color: #fff; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .expense_info.common_box_style.margintop { padding: 20px 13px; } table.cashflow { text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; } table.cashflow tr th { font-size: 19px; font-weight: normal; } table.cashflow tr td { font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; } .roi { display: inline-block; background: #2bb673; width: 99%; text-align: center; color: #000; padding: 10px 0px 20px 0; margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 6px; } .discliamer_sec { background: #dfe9e9; display: inline-block; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; width: 100%; padding: 10px 0; line-height: 18px; margin-top: 6px; } .discliamer_sec h2 { color: #768293; } .footer_cright { background: #496bb3; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; color: #fff; padding: 1px 0; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 7px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; } @media print { .common_box_style, .roi, .discliamer_sec, .footer_cright, .top_header { background: !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } } </style> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet'> </head> <body> <div class='main_wrapper'> <div class='top_header'> <div class='left_top'><p class='contact_person'>Xyz xyz<span>xyz@xyz.com</span></p><p class='contact_person right_person'>Xyz xyz<span>xyz@xyz.com</span></p></div> <div class='right_top'>";
    html +="<img src='images/logo.png' /></div> </div> <div class='galleryimage_main'> <img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+file1+"' alt='Gallery Image Here' height='350' width='885'/> </div> <div class='left_col'> <div class='property_address common_box_style margintop'> <h2>PROPERTY ADDRESS</h2> <p id='address_line_1' class='address_line_1'>4043 N RAVENSWOOD AVE,</p> <p id='address_line_2' class='address_line_2'>CSUITE 316, HICAGO,</p> </div> <div class='expense_info common_box_style margintop'> <h2>EXPENSE INFORMATION</h2> <table id='expense_information' class='expense_info' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1'> <tr> <th></th> <th>%of Rent</th> <th>Monthly</th> <th>Yearly</th> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Estimated Taxes:</td> <td>-</td> <td>345</td> <td>777</td> </tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Estimated Insurance:</td> <td>-</td> <td>200</td> <td>133</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Management Fee:</td> <td>4</td> <td>344</td> <td>5200</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Vacancy Adjustment:</td> <td>2</td> <td>555</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Repairs & Maintenance: </td> <td>10</td> <td>500</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr> </tr> <tr> </tr> <tr> </tr> <tr is='total_exp' class='total_exp'> <td class='exp_info_disc'>TOTAL EXPENSES:</td> <td></td> <td>343</td> <td>342</td> </tr> <tr> </tr><tr> </tr><tr> </tr> </table> </div> <div class='cashflow common_box_style margintop'> <h2>CASH FLOW ESTIMATE</h2> <table id='cashflow' class='cashflow' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='5'> <tr> <th>Per Month</th> <th>Per Year</th> </tr> <tr> <td>123</td> <td>4533</td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> <div class='right_col'> <div id='property_information' class='property_information common_box_style margintop'> <h2>PROPERTY Information</h2> <ul> <li><span>List Price:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span>Rehab Costs:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span>Structure:</span><span class='value_field'>Single Family</span></li> <li><span>Current Rent:</span><span class='value_field'>29</span></li> </ul> <ul class='grpleft'> <li><span>Bedrooms:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></li> <li><span>Bathrooms:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span>Square Footage:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span> Current Status:</span><span class='value_field'>Rented and Performing </span></li> </ul> <p class='cash_prize'>CASH PRICE<span>300</span></p> </div> <div class='gallery_small_images'> <div class='gallery_small_image2'> <img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+file2+"' /> </div> <div class='gallery_small_image3'> <img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+file3+"' /> </div></div> <div class='roi' id='cash_on_cash'> <h2>CASH-ON-CASH ROI</h2> <input type='text' value='1200' id='cash_roi_input'></input> </div> </div> <div class='discliamer_sec'> <h2>Information deemed reliabale but not guranteed. Images not to scale. Buyer responsible for <br>due diligence for all information provided and should conduct their own research.</h2> </div> <div class='footer_cright'> <h2>Copyright © High Return Real Estate LLC - 2017</h2> </div> </div> </body> </html>"; 
    var blob = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    //Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text.html");
    Utilities.sleep(30000);
    blob = blob.getBlob();
    var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
    Utilities.sleep(30000);
    DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");
}
```

Comment: It's better to convert the html to a pdf blob as follows: `var htmlOutPut = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);var pdfBlob = htmlOutPut.getAs("application/pdf");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the image file using URLfetchApp and convert it into a [base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739632/7465829) string and create a page with that. The remaining procedure is same as previous

```js
function htmlToPDF() {
   var file = []
     file[0]="0BweO_SXcQGqgcEV3Mk9QYVRMczQ"
    file[1]="0BweO_SXcQGqgVU93ZU56WkRkN3c"
    file[2]="0BweO_SXcQGqgMkIxTlhKajk5MFk"
    var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="
    var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+file[0])
    file[0] = img.getBlob().getContentType()+';base64,'+ Utilities.base64Encode(img.getBlob().getBytes())
    var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+file[1])
    file[1] = img.getBlob().getContentType()+';base64,'+ Utilities.base64Encode(img.getBlob().getBytes())
    var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+file[2])
    file[2] = img.getBlob().getContentType()+';base64,'+ Utilities.base64Encode(img.getBlob().getBytes())
    var html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'> <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> <title>High Return Real Estate</title> <style> @charset 'utf-8'; /* CSS Document */ body,html{ font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; background:#dfe7ea; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom:0; } .main_wrapper { width: 930px; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff; padding: 0 23px 0 23px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px -1px #bbbbbb; } .top_header { background: #dfe9e9; display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 6px; } .left_top { display: inline-block; width: 70%; padding: 26px 0 26px 50px; float: left; } p.contact_person.right_person { border-right: 0; padding-left: 25px; display: inline-block; } p.contact_person { width: 214px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #ccd4d3; } .left_top p span { font-size: 13px; color: #000; display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin-top: 2px; } .left_top p { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #ea9a5a; margin: 0; } .right_top img { border-top: 7px solid #496bb3; border-bottom: 7px solid #496bb3; padding: 16px 5px 13px 4px; } .right_top { display: inline-block; position: absolute; background: #fff; } .galleryimage_main img { width: 100%; display: inline-block; } .property_address { } .property_address p { font-size: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 4px; } .common_box_style { padding: 20px; background: #496bb3; text-transform: uppercase; } .common_box_style h2 { margin-top: 2px; color: #54bb73; font-size: 20px; } .property_information { margin-left: 6px; } .property_information ul li p { font-size: 15px; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 0; } .property_information ul li { list-style: none; margin-bottom: 5px; } .property_information ul li span { font-size: 15px; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 0; width: 100px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; } .property_information ul { padding-left: 0; width: auto; display: inline-block; float: left; margin-right: 15px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 4px; } .property_information ul li span.value_field { font-size: 13px; } ul.grpleft li span { width: 136px; } p.cash_prize { text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin: 0; } p.cash_prize span { padding-left: 10px; } .margintop{ margin-top: 6px; } .left_col { width: 34%; float: left; } .right_col { display: inline-block; width: 66%; } .gallery_small_images { display: inline-block; width: 99%; margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 6px; height: 232px; overflow: hidden; } .gallery_small_images img{ width:100%; } .gallery_small_image2 { width: 50%; float: left; } .gallery_small_image3 { width: 49%; display: inline-block; float: left; margin-left: 6px; } table.expense_info tr td.exp_info_disc { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: left; } tr.total_exp td { padding-top: 13px; padding-bottom: 30px; } .cashflow h2 { margin-bottom: 7px; } .roi input[type='text'] { font-size: 23px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; height: 33px; margin-bottom: 5px; } .roi h2 { margin-top: 24px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: 800; } tr.total_exp { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 4px; /* display: table; */ width: 100%; } table.expense_info th { font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; } td { font-size: 13px; color: #fff; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .expense_info.common_box_style.margintop { padding: 20px 13px; } table.cashflow { text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; color: #fff; text-transform: capitalize; } table.cashflow tr th { font-size: 19px; font-weight: normal; } table.cashflow tr td { font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; } .roi { display: inline-block; background: #2bb673; width: 99%; text-align: center; color: #000; padding: 10px 0px 20px 0; margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 6px; } .discliamer_sec { background: #dfe9e9; display: inline-block; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; width: 100%; padding: 10px 0; line-height: 18px; margin-top: 6px; } .discliamer_sec h2 { color: #768293; } .footer_cright { background: #496bb3; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; color: #fff; padding: 1px 0; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 7px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; } @media print { .common_box_style, .roi, .discliamer_sec, .footer_cright, .top_header { background: !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } } </style> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet'> </head> <body> <div class='main_wrapper'> <div class='top_header'> <div class='left_top'><p class='contact_person'>Xyz xyz<span>xyz@xyz.com</span></p><p class='contact_person right_person'>Xyz xyz<span>xyz@xyz.com</span></p></div> <div class='right_top'>";
    html +="<img src='images/logo.png' /></div> </div> <div class='galleryimage_main'> <img src='data:"+file[0]+"' alt='Gallery Image Here' height='350' width='885'/> </div> <div class='left_col'> <div class='property_address common_box_style margintop'> <h2>PROPERTY ADDRESS</h2> <p id='address_line_1' class='address_line_1'>4043 N RAVENSWOOD AVE,</p> <p id='address_line_2' class='address_line_2'>CSUITE 316, HICAGO,</p> </div> <div class='expense_info common_box_style margintop'> <h2>EXPENSE INFORMATION</h2> <table id='expense_information' class='expense_info' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1'> <tr> <th></th> <th>%of Rent</th> <th>Monthly</th> <th>Yearly</th> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Estimated Taxes:</td> <td>-</td> <td>345</td> <td>777</td> </tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Estimated Insurance:</td> <td>-</td> <td>200</td> <td>133</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Management Fee:</td> <td>4</td> <td>344</td> <td>5200</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Vacancy Adjustment:</td> <td>2</td> <td>555</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='exp_info_disc'>Repairs & Maintenance: </td> <td>10</td> <td>500</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr> </tr> <tr> </tr> <tr> </tr> <tr is='total_exp' class='total_exp'> <td class='exp_info_disc'>TOTAL EXPENSES:</td> <td></td> <td>343</td> <td>342</td> </tr> <tr> </tr><tr> </tr><tr> </tr> </table> </div> <div class='cashflow common_box_style margintop'> <h2>CASH FLOW ESTIMATE</h2> <table id='cashflow' class='cashflow' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='5'> <tr> <th>Per Month</th> <th>Per Year</th> </tr> <tr> <td>123</td> <td>4533</td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> <div class='right_col'> <div id='property_information' class='property_information common_box_style margintop'> <h2>PROPERTY Information</h2> <ul> <li><span>List Price:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span>Rehab Costs:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span>Structure:</span><span class='value_field'>Single Family</span></li> <li><span>Current Rent:</span><span class='value_field'>29</span></li> </ul> <ul class='grpleft'> <li><span>Bedrooms:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></li> <li><span>Bathrooms:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span>Square Footage:</span><span class='value_field'>100</span></p></li> <li><span> Current Status:</span><span class='value_field'>Rented and Performing </span></li> </ul> <p class='cash_prize'>CASH PRICE<span>300</span></p> </div> <div class='gallery_small_images'> <div class='gallery_small_image2'> <img src='data:"+file[1]+"' /> </div> <div class='gallery_small_image3'> <img src='data:"+file[2]+"' /> </div></div> <div class='roi' id='cash_on_cash'> <h2>CASH-ON-CASH ROI</h2> <input type='text' value='1200' id='cash_roi_input'></input> </div> </div> <div class='discliamer_sec'> <h2>Information deemed reliabale but not guranteed. Images not to scale. Buyer responsible for <br>due diligence for all information provided and should conduct their own research.</h2> </div> <div class='footer_cright'> <h2>Copyright © High Return Real Estate LLC - 2017</h2> </div> </div> </body> </html>"; 
    var blob = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    //Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text.html");
    
    blob = blob.getBlob();
    var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
    
    
    DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * This function retrieve the html body.
 * Using regex searches all the images src attribute and create array of image URLs
 * Iterate over imageURL & retrieve image blob from URLFetchApp and convert it into base64
 * Then replaces the imageURL with base64 with proper formatting
 * Then convert the htmlText to PDF and save it in folder
 * @param {string} messageID
 * @param {string} folderID
 * @param {string} fileURL
 */
function convertMailBodyToPDF(messageID, folderID) {
  const mail = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageID);
  let htmlText = mail.getBody();
  const images = getAllImageTags(htmlText);
  images.forEach(image => {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(image);
    const imgbase64 = "data:" + res.getBlob().getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(res.getBlob().getBytes());
    htmlText = replaceAll(htmlText, image, imgbase64);
  });
  const blob = htmlToPDF(htmlText);
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(blob).setName("testimage.pdf");
  console.log(file.getUrl());
  return file.getUrl();
}

/**
 * This converts html to pdf blob
 * @param {string} text
 * @param {Blob} blob
 */
function htmlToPDF(text) {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text);
  const blob = html.getBlob();
  return blob.getAs("application/pdf");
}

/**
 * Retrieve all image src
 * @param {string} str
 * @return {Array} imageURL
 */
function getAllImageTags(str) {
  let words = [];
  str.replace(/<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)"/g, function ($0, $1) { words.push($1) });
  return words;
}

const escapeRegExp = (string) => string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
const replaceAll = (str, find, replace) => str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
```

Answer (score 1):

You saved me with this:

```
> const images = getAllImageTags(htmlText);   images.forEach(image => {
>     const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(image);
>     const imgbase64 = "data:" + res.getBlob().getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(res.getBlob().getBytes());
>     htmlText = replaceAll(htmlText, image, imgbase64);   });
```

I just edited it:

```
htmlText  = htmlText.replace(image, imgbase64);
```

I needed to Compile a Google Doc Template that I have in DRIVE which is a letterhead with a Header and a Footer which are images and as body there are Placeholders, ex. {{name}} {{surname}}; finally upload to DRIVE as a PDF.
So the steps were:

1. from DOC to HTML
2. from HTML to BLOB
3. from BLOB to PDF

Everything worked correctly, but in the conversion to PDF I was missing the images... which had to be replaced by the same images but converted to Base64 ... and your procedure works great!

Thanks!!!!!!