# Google Apps Script - Images not showing when creating PDF from HTML

Tags: html, image, pdf, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that will output a PDF with values that have been inputted into a form. On this PDF, I would like to include a logo at the top of the page, which is an image in a Google Drive folder.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941270/create-pdf-from-html-in-google-apps-script-and-include-images-images-not-showi) (and others), the image needs to be converted to base64 and then added to the HTML.

My issue is that even when I do this, the image still does not show up in the PDF file.

Here is my current code, just trying to output a PDF with the image, and nothing else

```
function htmlToPDF() {
  var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pHu-JPLA4Ml6R5Mc7pktLtqCAcGepLMG"
  var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var b64 = img.getBlob().getContentType() + ";base64," + Utilities.base64Encode(img.getBlob().getBytes());
  var html_img = "<img src=\"data:" + b64 + "\" >";

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html_img, "text/html", "text.html")
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
  DriveApp.getFolderById('1o-yYvlNmdRYsH-J6b31wrT2GYfkCQEGG').createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");
}
```

Here is what I get when I run this script
[image: Output of htmlToPDF]

Thank you!

Comment: I think that your script works, and the image is displayed in the PDF data. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, when you modify `export=view` to `export=download`, what result will you obtain? By the way, what mimeType is your image?

Comment: @Tanaike Yeah, changing it to `export=download` didn't affect anything. For mimeType, the `.getContentType()` method returns `text/html`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `For mimeType, the .getContentType() method returns text/html`, in this case, your image you want to put is the HTML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modified Code

```js
/**
 * Creates an HTML <img> tag from an image file ID
 */
function imgToHtmlTag(fileId) {
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)
  let fileBlob = file.getBlob()
  let imgData = fileBlob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(fileBlob.getBytes())

  return "<img src='data:" + imgData + "' />"
}

/**
 * Creates a pdf called "test" in your drive based on HTML input
 */
function createPdfFromHtml(html) {
  var blob = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  blob = blob.getBlob();
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("test.pdf");
}

/**
 * Function to test above functions
 */
function test() {
  var fileId = "[IMG_DRIVE_FILE_ID]"
  let html = imgToHtmlTag(fileId)
  createPdfFromHtml(html)
}
}
```

I changed a couple things from your script:

- Instead of using `urlFetchApp` to get the images, I just used the inbuilt [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)
- I refactored it into separate functions to make it easier to follow.

This script works for me. I am not sure exactly why your script fails but if this doesn't work either, then try changing the image file.

#### Reference

- [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)